# Mirrored display isn't "full screen"

Tags: windows-8, laptop, multiple-monitors, hdmi, tv

I plugged my laptop into my TV via HDMI, both displays are 1920x1080 and I have it set to Mirror my laptops display onto the TV.

It does so, except I have a black border around the display on the TV, as if my laptop is only taking up 90% of the screen horizontally and vertically or so.

Tried messing around with the ATI Catalyst Control Center but couldn't find any settings... No idea what could be causing this? I've found similar queries where the aspect ratio of the secondary display is off, but that's not quite what's happening here...

Answer (score 1):

The issue you are having is [underscan](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/underscan) - There is no Wikipedia entry for underscan, as it is a facet of [overscan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overscan).

I had a similar issues with connecting laptops to my TVs, but my issue was [overscan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overscan), where the image displayed is larger than the resolution of the TV.  The fix is the same for both though.

If you had NVidia cards, the solution is easy with the NVidia control panel.  However, I do not have or use ATI cards, so I cant say a particular solution works.

However Googling "fix ati underscan" shows there are a variety of [solutions](https://www.google.com/search?q=fix%20ati%20underscan&rlz=1C1CHFX_enUS513US513&oq=fix%20ati%20underscan&aqs=chrome..69i57.3832j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=0&ie=UTF-8).

Comment: Thanks, I messed around with my TV settings a bunch and got it to be *almost* 100% used, probably 99.9% of it is so at a good viewing distance the tiny border was unnoticable. I'll look into this more later when I'm not at work, though!